# How to write Text in css like show in images?

Tags: css

[image: Image shoe text style]

Please tell me how to write text like these using CSS3. Please give me an answer.

```
<header>TEST</header>
```

Comment: better use custom fonts.. using @font-face.. Make sure you are using `.ttf` `.otf`, `.svg` all formts to work in every system or any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likes of [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) will allow you to alter the type faces for this. The below snippet suggests the basic use of this:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light);

div{
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  padding:30px;
  font-size:30px;
  background:gray;
  displaY:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
plain text
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css Fonts. Other than that it cant be done using css